# Broadcast a message on Inet 4.4.0

Tags: c++, omnet++, broadcast, inet

I work with INET4.4.0, and I would like to send a broadcast message to all nodes in the network. For this, I tried to add this instruction in the `omnetpp.ini` file:

`*.host.networkLayer.ip.forceBroadcast = true`

but INET does not recognize this instruction.

- When I looked in `INET4.4/networklayer/ipv4.ned/`, I didn't find the `forceBroadcast` parameter.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: `omnetpp.ini` does not contain instructions. It is used for setting values of the parameters of a network. You have correctly stated that there is no parameter `forceBroadcast` in IPv4. So you should not be surprised that INET doesn't recognize that parameter.

Comment: So, how to ensure  the broadcast in inet4.4.0?
Because with the old version of INET, you just have to initialize in omnet.ini forceBrodcat to true

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that parameter name has changed and there are two parameters instead:

```
bool limitedBroadcast = default(false); // send out limited broadcast packets coming from higher layer
string directBroadcastInterfaces = default("");   // list of interfaces that direct broadcast is enabled (by default direct broadcast is disabled on all interfaces)
```

But probably a better approach would be to do the same as with an application in the real world. Use the broadcast address (`255.255.255.255`) as a destination address in your UDP application.